# Url redirect 2 times when access from www

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to investigate the issue redirect when using www and HTTP link.
Currently, if I use HTTP link with www.domain then it will redirect 2 times 301 > 302 > 200. I check via site: https://wheregoes.com/trace/20222001706/
[image]
The remain case it just redirect 1 time from HTTP to https

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /root/ssl/ins_multi_domain_new_2021_to_2022_cert_chain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/ins_multi_domain_new_2021_to_2022.com.key;

  server_name ins.com www.ins.com *.ins.com;
  root /var/www/html/ins;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
  }

  # disable access to hidden files
  location ~ /\.ht {
     # access_log off;
    #  log_not_found off;
      deny all;
  }

 #browser caching of static assets
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }

    #browser caching of css and js
    location ~*  \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 14d;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/x-component
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml;

  #for varnish
    #ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ins.com www.ins.com;
  root /var/www/html/ins;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081/;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
                proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
}
}

upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Does anyone have experience with these issues? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a http to https redirect (First one)
- There is a www to non-www redirect (Second one)

Make sure you have 1 redirect which point instantly to the right variant.

Typically, there are 4 entry points:

1. `http www`
2. `http non-www`
3. `https www`
4. `https non-www`

In your case you want to use a `https non-www` one I guess? You need to pick the one you want to use, and redirect all other (with one rule) to it.

So in your case, redirect variants 1, 2 and 3 to variant 4.

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect every url to point #4 https://ins.com
So, May I know the rule or edit code nginx for that?

Comment: I am not an Nginx expert. Did you search for `nginx redirect all to https non-www`? Take a look here, first hit is what you are looking for I guess?  https://serverfault.com/questions/258378/remove-www-and-redirect-to-https-with-nginx